# How do I revoke my own group admin privileges in Yammer

Tags: yammer

After switching departments, I noticed I am still an admin for a group from my previous department.  This group has a second admin as well.

How do I remove myself as an admin from this group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the group in question.
2. Select the members link, just above the member picture thumbnails.
3. Find yourself in the list.
4. Click the down arrow and select Revoke Admin

[image]